# React Native Context with Array

Tags: react-native, react-context

I am new to react native and trying to create React Native context which will store array of objects. Context looks something like this:

```
import React, {useState, useCallback} from 'react';

export const NotificationContext = React.createContext({
  notifications: [],
  updateNotifications: () => {},
});

export default function NotificationContextProvider({children}) {
  const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);

  const updateNotifications = n => {
    notifications.push(n);
    setNotifications(notifications);
  };
  const contextValue = {
    notifications,
    updateNotifications: useCallback(n => updateNotifications(n), []),
  };

  return (
    <NotificationContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </NotificationContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Now when I am trying to access the context, I am not getting the updated array value as desired.

```
var context = useContext(NotificationContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      
      console.log('Before', context);
      console.log('Notification value', context.notifications);

      context.updateNotifications([1]);
      console.log('After', context);
      
    })();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass dependencies variable context in useEffect

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).